# Aurora Borealis in Oulu

Tags: finland, auroras

I am planning to go to Oulu in February for 4 days. What are the chances of seeing Aurora Borealis and are there some tours available? Would there be a significantly better chance of seeing the aurorae further north in Rovaniemi?

Comment: Not really an answer, but there are forecast websites like this: http://www.aurora-service.eu/aurora-forecast . They can help you get the feel for the places you have to go to for the best chances.

Comment: Please, we don't need to close as "opinion-based" just because the question says "better".

Comment: I fail to understand how is it an opinion based question. I have asked if there are tours available from Oulu. I also asked if there is a better chance if I travel to Rovaniemi. The answer for this could be yes or no based on what people have experience in past.

Answer (score 1):

**Your odds are good but not great.**

The season is good, since while the peak season for auroras in Oulu ("O" in the graph below) is April, but there's a fair amount of activity in February as well.

[image]
(courtesy Finnish Meteorological Institute)

However, the incidence of auroras drops rapidly as you go south.  Per [this page from the Finnish Meteorological Institute](https://ilmatieteenlaitos.fi/tiedote/1032265372) (in Finnish), in northernmost Finland, 3 out of 4 nights have auroras, but around Rovaniemi that falls to 50% and in Oulu only 1 out of 3.  Remember that these are statistical averages: if it's cloudy, you won't see anything, since aurora are far above the clouds.

And yes, there are tours from Oulu, [here's one](https://www.eventours.fi/in-english/aurorahunting/) selected at random.  Rovaniemi is a much larger tourist destination though and will have more options.